# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in PHP

Tags: php

My **logout.php** file is like this. Is there any mistake in my code

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location:index.php');
exit;
?>
```

Here is my **index.php** file. If I am set `$_SESSION['s_activId']` then it is working properly but when I am trying to put condition if `$_SESSION['s_activId']` is not set at that time I want to pass header on index page sometimes it works sometimes it does not work.

```
<?php
include('include/config.inc.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['s_activId']))
{
  $_SESSION['s_urlRedirectDir'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location:index.php");
}
else
{
  $wrong = '';
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $checkLogin = "SELECT userName,password,userType
                     FROM user
                    WHERE BINARY userName = '".$_POST['userName']."'
                      AND BINARY password = '".$_REQUEST['password']."'";
    $checkLoginresult = mysql_query($checkLogin);
    if($userLoginRow = mysql_fetch_array($checkLoginresult))
    {
      $_SESSION['s_activId']   = $userLoginRow['userName'];
      $_SESSION['s_password']  = $userLoginRow['password'];
      $_SESSION['hg_userType'] = $userLoginRow['userType'];
     
     if(!$_SESSION['s_urlRedirectDir'])
      {
        header("Location:index.php");
      }
      else
      {
        header("Location:reminder.php");
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $wrong = "UserId And Password Is Not Valid";
    }
  }
}
include("bottom.php");
$smarty->assign('wrong',$wrong);
$smarty->display("index.tpl");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem arise in the condition below in **index.php**:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['s_activId']))
{
    $_SESSION['s_urlRedirectDir'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

When you logout, you are calling `session_destroy()` on **logout.php** and redirecting on **index.php** and the condition above gets `true` as `s_activId` is not set in session and again you are redirecting on **index.php** (without setting `s_activId` in session). The above condition will be true until the variable `s_activId` set in session and because of this you are getting `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

The solution is, on **index.php** set the variable `s_activId` in session before calling the `header` method. Refer the code below:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['s_activId']))
{
    $_SESSION['s_urlRedirectDir'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $_SESSION['s_activId'] = true;
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

Comment: Ideally it should fix the problem, if you have applied the fix exactly same i explained.

Comment: i am fixed this code in my index.php file than index page became blank..

Comment: if it's blank there should be some error, keep error reporting on to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

> Dont redirect index.php to index.php. you having redirects loop. Also
>   if you have code below that also can fire add die in if because after
>   redirect code below still executes.  I didnt read your code, maybe
>   there isnt problems with this but after

```
header("Location: lalala"); always add die(); or exit();
```