# send html template in php

Tags: php, html

My Php mail code is like this i want to send html content in mail but i can not send html template with this code

```
                    $to = $email;;
                    $subject = 'New Order Detail';
                    $message = 'Hi Jane'; 
                    $from = 'info@abc.co.in';

                    // Sending email
                    if(mail($to, $subject, $message))
                    {
                        echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
                        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

                        // Create email headers
                        $headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
                            'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
                            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                        // Compose a simple HTML email message
                        $message = '<html><body>';
                        $message = '<table border="1" align="center" width="50%">';
                        $message .= '<tr><td>Test Mail';
                        $message .= '</td></tr>';
                        //$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">Will you marry me?</p>';
                        $message .= '</table>';
                        $message .= '</body></html>';

                        // Sending email
                        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
                        {
                            echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
                        } else
                        {
                            echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
                        }
                    }
```

This kind of output i get in mail i do not know where is my mistake in this code..
**Output**

```
<html><body>
<table border="1" align="center" width="50%">
<tr><td>Test Mail</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code and also wrong `if statement` I would like to recommend following script to you for sending email.

```
$to = $email;
$subject = 'New Order Detail';
$message_text = 'Hi Jane'; 
$from = 'info@abc.co.in';
$from_name = 'John';
$to_name   = 'Smith';

// Sending email
if(!empty($to) && !empty($message_text ))
{   
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Create email headers
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: ' . ucwords($to_name) .' <'.$to.'>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . ucwords($from_name) . ' <'. $from. '>' ."\r\n";

    // Compose a simple HTML email message
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message = '<table border="1" align="center" width="50%">';
    $message .= '<tr><td>Test Mail';
    $message .= '</td></tr>';
    $message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">'.$message_text .'</p>';
    $message .= '</table>';
    $message .= '</body></html>';

    // Sending email
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
}else{
    echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
}
```

Comment: and i want to use css code in this code how should i apply.. and also i want to send this template to 5 email id at same time so what i have to do..

Comment: You can use inline css properties which will be work. For example `<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">`

Comment: ok thanks and another question is it's possible which mail i am send though this code it's also show in my sent box..

Comment: Sorry i click on another answer that is why that happen

Comment: i want to add image in mail but i can not send image in mail

Comment: @ChandreshMandaliya You can add image in email for that task you need to upload image on server and use that link inside `img` tag. For example `<img src="www.xyz.com/your-image.png"` />

Comment: $message .= '<td><img width="100" height="100" src="www.abc.co.in/_cat_img/'.$o_img.'"></td></tr>';

Comment: can you help me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910606/err-too-many-redirects-in-php/44919281?noredirect=1#comment76961017_44919281

Comment: i want to send email reply to my own webmail how ios it possible i have to just mention that web mail id in cc or bcc or i have to do something else..

Answer (score 0):

add proper header contents.

```
  // Compose a simple HTML email message
              $message = '<html><body>';
              $message = '<table border="1" align="center" width="50%">';
              $message .= '<tr><td>Test Mail';
              $message .= '</td></tr>';
              //$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">Will you marry me?</p>';
              $message .= '</table>';
              $message .= '</body></html>';


 $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
 $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'To: abc <abc@example.com>, xyz <xyz@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'From: ABC <Abc@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: abc@example.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: xyz@example.com';

 // Mail it
 mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your character set to UTF-8:

```
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/  html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on a theme perhaps and redundant as you have an answer. You should be able to add styles within the `style` tag region of the below code - or you could potentially add a link to an external css file but that could cause issues.

```
$to = $email;
$subject = 'New Order Detail';
$message = 'Hi Jane'; 
$from = 'info@abc.co.in';

$obj=new StdClass;
$obj->success='Your mail has been sent successfully.';
$obj->fail='Unable to send email. Please try again.';
$obj->nl="\r\n";


$status = @mail( $to, $subject, $message );


if( $status ) {
    exit( $obj->success );
} else {

    $headers = array();
    $html = array();

    $headers[]="MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[]="From: {$from}";
    $headers[]="Reply-To: {$from}";
    $headers[]="X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
    $headers[]="MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[]="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";

    $html[]="";
    $html[]="<html>";
    $html[]="<head>";
    $html[]="<title>{$subject}</title>";
    $html[]="<style>";
    $html[]="p{color:red;font-size:18px;}";
    $html[]="table{border:1px solid black;width:50%;display:table;}";
    $html[]="td{text-align:center;background:yellow;color:blue;}";
    $html[]="</style>";
    $html[]="</head>";
    $html[]="<body>";
    $html[]="<table>";
    $html[]="<tr><td>Test Mail</td></tr>";
    $html[]="<tr><td><p>Will you marry me?</p></td></tr>";
    $html[]="</table>";
    $html[]="</body>";
    $html[]="</html>";


    $status = @mail( $to, $subject, implode( $obj->nl, $html ), implode( $obj->nl, $headers ) );


    exit( $status ? $obj->success : $obj->fail );
}
```